# SVG file expoerted flat in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm doing a simple landing page using flutter. When I try to use an SVG file, the file somehow is flat, isn't it supposed to be not flat??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:simple_app/my_icon.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           Container(
            height: size.height*0.6 ,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
             child: Column(
               children: <Widget> [
                 Align(
                     child: SvgPicture.asset(
                         dika,
                     ),
                   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                 ),
               ],
             ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: does your .svg file look normal when you simply open it?

Comment: yes, it does load like a normal .svg

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine, I assume your .svg file is broken, you could try to remove shadows and filter effects from your svg, they're not supported.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: size.height*0.6 ,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              Align(
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/hexagon.svg',
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

SVG in top left corner:

[image: simulator]